# Custom Field in Order

Tags: wordpress

I am building a store based on MarketPress full version (http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/e-commerce) in Wordpress multisite setup.

I ran into the need of having 1 extra field in each item being ordered (i.e: an image (which is basically a url pointing to the image) to be printed on a selected product).

I have taken a look and try several things but I haven't see the light yet.

Can someone help, please? Any advices to get on the right direction are all appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this forum answer from the Lead Developer of MarketPress concerning custom fields for the products:

http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/custom-fields-for-marketpress